# Split counter to array and prepend html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, counter

I'm trying to split the numbers in a counter so I can style each digit individually, I've got this so far but can't get seems to get the numbers.

You can check the code on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/553785/,

did not work on here and I made it so that the number needs to be added to the field before it start. A requirement of the counter.

Thanks & Regards

```js
jQuery(function() {

  $("#countValue").on("keyup change", function() {
    counter = this.value;
    $("#count").text(value);
  });

  if (typeof(localStorage.getItem('counts')) != 'object') {
    counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counts'));
  }
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#count").html(counter);
    ++counter;
    localStorage.setItem('counts', counter);
  }, 2000);

  console.log(counter);


  $("#countValue").focusout(function() {
    $(".hideinput").hide();
  });


  // $('div .number').each(function() {
  //     var number = $(this).text();
  //     var i = 0;

  // $(this).parent().prepend($("<span class='nNumber'></span>"));
  // while (i < number.length) {
  //     $(this).hide();
  //     var nChar = number.charAt(i);
  //     $(this).parent().find('.nNumber').append('<span class="digit-' + nChar + '">' + nChar + '</span>');
  //     i++;
  // }
  // });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="counterParent">
  <h1 id="count" class="number"></h1>
</div>


<!-- Result as below

        <h1 id="count" class="number">
          <span class="num">0</span>
          <span class="num">0</span>
          <span class="num">0</span>
          <span class="num">0</span>          
        </h1>

-->

<div class="hideinput">
  <input type="text" id="countValue">
</div>
```

Comment: i really don't understand what do you want to reach. Show an example how it should to look like.

Comment: Basically, at the moment the counter is rendering as a single string. I need to change it to an array and so I can enclose each digit with an html tag (span or div) so each digit can be styled individually.

Comment: example please how it should to look like.

Comment: updated jsfiddle with sample after split [Updated Fiddle] [http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/553881/]

Comment: so you want to count how much time the user has inputted something ?

Comment: Nope, its just a counter that a user will enter a number into and it starts counting. I need that number to be converted into array and enclose each digit with an html tag so I can style them

Comment: can you please show me an example like a text or something like this what do you want to reach because i don't really understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version without `setTimeout`s and `localStorage`.

Each digit will become `span` with `class="digit-1/2/3/etc"`.

```js
const toHtml = value => value
    .split('')
    .map((x, i) => `<span class="digit-${i}">${x}</span>`)
    .join('')

$('#input').on('input', function() {
  $('#root').html(toHtml(this.value))
  localStorage.setItem('count', this.value)
})

$('#input').val(localStorage.getItem('count') || '')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" />
<div id="root"></div>
```

I'm sure, you can pick this up, customize and apply to your own example.

**Update**: replaced colors with CSS class
**Update**: add `localStorage` usage, note that here in SO it is not allowed to work with `localStorage`, a working example can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/buserofepe/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks @amankkg, not quite what I was after but will adapt accordingly.

Comment: this code answers the title question, but I can update it to your needs

Comment: the string I mean is for example  a bunch of numbers like "123456" and split them up into <span>1</span> <span>2</span> and so forth, whilst at the same time being stored to local storage so when the page refreshes the last count is called and not reset from 0. The styling would come from css. Rgds Said

Comment: code above is actually splits string like "12345" into `<span class="digit-1">1</span><span class="digit-2">2</span>...`, usage of `localStorage` is trivial, I can add it

Comment: hey @Said, I updated the code with `localStorage` usage, you can check it out here http://jsbin.com/buserofepe/edit?html,js,output, hope it helps